# Capturing output from a shell command without [also] sending its output to stdout

Tags: unix, perl

I am writing a Perl program to get the modified time of a particular file. I have tried the following scenarios:

1. `$time = system("stat -c %y temp.txt")` --> this sets $time to "0" and writes "2013-04-03 06:10:02.000000000 -0600" to stdout.
2. `` $time = `stat -c %y temp.txt` `` --> this sets $time to "2013-04-03 06:10:02.000000000 -0600" and also displays the same thing ("2013-04-03 06:10:02.000000000 -0600") on stdout.
3. `$time = exec("stat -c %y temp.txt")` --> this does not set $time but prints "2013-04-03 06:10:02.000000000 -0600" on stdout.

As this is flooding my stdout with the same type of data again and again, I want to get rid of it. Can please somebody help me in this?

Comment: Redirect the o/p to `/dev/null`. Something like `./script > /dev/null`

Comment: How about `$time =exec("stat -c %y temp.txt 2>/dev/null")` ? does this work?

Comment: FYI, the return value from `system()` is probably the exit status of the command (which is typically zero for success and non-zero for failure).

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using perl's built-in `stat` function:

```
@st = stat('temp.txt');
```

`$st[9]` now contains the Unix epoch timestamp for the last-modified time.  You could get it into a more useful format like this

```
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($st[9]);
```

or just get a printable string like this

```
$time = localtime($st[9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Backticks (and the related `qx` operator or `readpipe` function) do not write any output on standard output; they execute a command, capture the command's output and return it (usually to assign it to some variable). So

```
$time = `stat -c %y temp.txt`
```

will set `$time` and not write anything to standard output. It is possible for the command to write something to standard error, but from the symptoms you describe, it doesn't look like that is what's happening.